# How to create Tkinter background image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Python standalone application for macOS and am building the interface. I am trying to use Tkinter to create a background with some boxes in it but I get an error. If anyone knows a fix that would be greatly appreciated:

The error I get:

```
>>> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "./landscape.jpg"
```

Here is the python3 script for creating it:

```
import tkinter as tk import requests from PIL import Image, ImageTk

app = tk.Tk()

HEIGHT = 700 WIDTH = 600

C = tk.Canvas(app, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH) background_image= tk.PhotoImage(file='./landscape.jpg') background_label = tk.Label(app, image=background_image) background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

C.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(app,  bg='#42c2f4', bd=5) frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')
#frame_window = C.create_window(100, 40, window=frame) lower_frame = tk.Frame(app, bg='#42c2f4', bd=10) lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

bg_color = 'white' results = tk.Label(lower_frame, anchor='nw', justify='left', bd=4) results.config(font=40, bg=bg_color) results.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better check whether the image is a jpeg image actually.

Comment: @acw1668 it is, I checked

Comment: Use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` instead of `tk.PhotoImage(...)`.

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage` can't open .jpeg files but .png, .pgm/.ppm and .gif instead. For beeing able to use .jpeg images use  `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` with an `PIL.ImageTk.Image` object.